# Best Practice to run commands after starting up a prebuilt docker image

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, bitnami

What is best practice to run code after downloading AND spinning up a prebuilt Docker Image? For example, I use Bitnamis RabbitMQ image that spins up a container running RabbitMQ (obviously): https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/rabbitmq

After the container has spun up and RabbitMQ is running I want to download and enable an additional RabbitMQ-Plugin. There are two problems I encounter as a Docker-Newbie:

1. RabbitMQ takes some time to initialize, maybe 20-30 seconds
2. The Plugin needs to be enabled after said initialization has finished

Right now, I spin up the container, wait for 30 seconds and manually exec a command on the terminal like

> docker exec -it  wget -O /plugins/folder/newplugin.ez https://pluginlocation.com/newplugin.ez && rabbitmq-plugins enable newplugin`

This works, but is there a recommended way to do all this in one go? I tried using my own Dockerfile on top of the process:

> FROM bitnami/rabbitmq:latest
>
> RUN wget -O /plugins/folder/newplugin.ez https://pluginlocation.com/newplugin.ez
>
> RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable newplugin

But at this point, RabbitMQ is not initialized yet so enabling the plugin fails.

Best
-act

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That is wrong, you can have as many `RUN` instructions as you have layers. You are probably mixing this up with `CMD`.

Comment: @ErikDannenberg - Yes, I am mixing it up :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable a plugin without having a running broker with the `--offline` option.
So your `Dockerfile` could be:

```
FROM bitnami/rabbitmq:latest

RUN curl -o /opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/plugins/newplugin.ez \
            https://pluginlocation.com/newplugin.ez \
 && rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline newplugin
```

BTW, it's a [good practice](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#minimize-the-number-of-layers) to do related things (e.g. downloading and enabling a plugin) in one layer.

Comment: Thank you @zigarn, the offline-option was exactly what I needed to add!